# How to keep on-screen keyboard from disappearing when focus changes from one text field to another

Tags: javascript, android, ipad

I've got an HTML5 app that uses a some input type="text" fields for entering text.  I am catching keystroke events in order to link together certain fields.

I am having problems when testing this on any mobile device.  Initially I tried it on an iPad using Safari or Chrome. However, later I also tried it on an android device running the latest version of Mobile Firefox and experienced the same problem.

The issue is that as soon as the input element changes, the on-screen keyboard goes away.  I have tried doing this in several different ways but it always seems to produce the same effect - as soon as I focus() on a different text input, the keyboard disappears.  This represents a serious impediment to flow, as it requires an extra motion to correctly re-select a text field that is already selected and should have focus and get keyboard input.  On a small device such as a phone it is even worse, as all of this is accompanied by zooming and panning as the removal and re-display of the keyboard causes the page to re-render.  This is similar in severity to what would happen if one's keyboard would stop working and require replugging every time one hit enter when editing a text document - it clearly would be a critical issue.

The following minimal code reproduces the problem:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  :focus { color: red; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
var tf1 = document.getElementById('tf1')
var tf2 = document.getElementById('tf2')
tf1.focus()                                                                                                                                         
tf1.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    if (evt.which == KeyEvent.DOM_VK_RETURN
        || evt.which == KeyEvent.DOM_VK_Q
        || evt.which == KeyEvent.DOM_VK_ENTER) {
        tf2.focus()
        if (evt.stopPropogation) evt.stopPropogation()
        if (evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault()
        return false
        }
    }
}
</script>
<body onload="init()">
<input type='text' id='tf1' value='field1' />
<input type='text' id='tf2' value='field2' />
</body>
</html>
```

First thing I note is that, while the initial focus() works (the element turns red) the on-screen keyboard does not appear.  While this is troubling, it is not a huge deal to tap to initially tap a text field.  However, as soon as I press any of the triggering keys (I have thrown an ordinary character in there to confirm that it doesn't matter what it is), suddenly the keyboard disappears.  This doesn't make any sense to me, not only is a text element still focused, which requires the on-screen keyboard, but it was a keyboard event that changed the focus, which would suggest that the keyboard might still be needed - it's not like I did this from a delay or something.

I have tried onkeydown, onkeyup, and onkeypress - all exhibit the same behavior.

How can I keep the on-screen keyboard from going away?  I have wasted a lot of time trying to get this one critical piece of functionality to work, and it still doesn't!  Is there some sort of meta-tag I need to include or something?  Or is the just a pervasive, cross-platform bug that all mobile devices have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `click()` method instead of or after `tf1.focus()`;

Like this:

```
tf1.click();
```

This may cause little to no software keyboard hiding.

Comment: so far so good, this fixes the problem on Android.  I'll confirm it on iOS and then accept.

Comment: alas, this does not fix the problem on iOS 7... without the focus(), the field does not change, and the click(), either before or after the focus() does not prevent the on-screen keyboard from going away...

Comment: IOS software keyboards provide previous and next buttons as the means for moving to and from various html input:text fields.  You would have to create an html input:button within your html app and let it call tf2.focus() to properly move focus() to any particular input:text field(s) for the keyboard to remain visible.  So, from IOS's point of view, it could be unnecessary to have an html app moving focus to other input:text fields via the return key or any other key, for example, when a mechanism for doing that is already provided on IOS devices.  I hope this is somewhat helpful.

Comment: i understand what you're saying, but it kinda sounds like Apple simply isn't anticipating and therefore isn't allowing the behavior i'm trying to implement.  having to do anything other than simply typing is completely breaking the perception my real app is trying to provide.

Comment: accepting based on solution working for android.  pretty much looks like what i'm trying to do is not possible on iOS (Apple disappoints again)... not much I can do except simply drop all support for that platform.